# Normal distribution function in matlab

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

apologies for the silly question, mathematics is not my strong point. I am trying to design a function in matlab that generates samples according to a normal distribution N(mu, sigma) in d-dimensions. This is the code I have so far,

```
mu = [1 2];
Sigma = [1 .5; .5 2]; R = chol(Sigma);
z = repmat(mu,100,1) + randn(100,2)*R;
```

I've found this from reading through various wikipedia and google articles and was wondering if it is correct? Thanks in advance,

rusty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - yes.

Slightly longer answer - why not try it yourself?

```
>> z = repmat(mu,1000000,1) + randn(1000000,2)*R;
>> mean(z)
ans =
        1.001       2.0005
>> cov(z)
ans =
      0.99937      0.49942
      0.49942       2.0017
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I have another similar question, what is the difference between using randn() like I have above or mvnrnd(MU,SIGMA) to generate normal samples, is mvnrnd used for dimensions larger than 2 ?

Comment: `randn` is not multivariate exactly, it just generates normal numbers independently in each dimension. You can't force a covariance. `mvnrnd` is for generating samples from a proper multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: As Ansari points out, randn is at once both multi-variate and univariate, although if you have an identity covariance matrix, then the dimensions are independent. Use of randn as you did is an entirely valid way to generate a sample with a given covariance matrix and mean, but mvnrnd gives you the general case for any parameter set. The method you found is entirely valid for higher numbers of dimensions.